# Баг плавного скролла якорей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал скрипт, чтобы при клике по ссылке якорю, скролл плавно переносил на пункт. Вот в чем проблема скролл плавно переходит и проблем нет, но при повторном клике на одну и туже ссылку возможность прокрутки тупо пропадает, то есть, крутя колесико мыши либо перетаскивая скролл все тупо стоит на месте и не двигается, но через несколько попыток проходит. В консоле чисто поэтому у меня даже мыслей нет из-за чего возникла такая проблема.

```
//Anchor Scroll
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
  destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
  var scrolling = destination - 100;
  $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop: scrolling }, 500 );
  });
});
```

Comment: При повторном клике на ссылку, которая должна скролить? или на любую? или при двойном клике на кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно глупая ошибка,при нескольких кликах по ссылке запускается несколько анимаций, поэтому пока не проходит время, отсутствует возможность скролла вообще, поэтому просто задаем условие сравнения позиции элемента и скролла , чтобы анимация не запускалась:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
clickElement =  $(this).attr("href");
destination = $(clickElement).offset().top;
var scrolling = destination - 100;
scrolling = parseInt(scrolling);
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
position = parseInt(position);
if(scrolling != position){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: scrolling}, 500);
    }
});
```